# Javascript Form validation with substr

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

This is part of a javascript to validate a form. This checks to see if it is empty.

```
if (form.redoarr.value == "") {
    alert("Has to be higher");
    form.redoarr.focus();
return false;
}
```

I want to make sure that the 4 digit number entered begins with a 2 digit number under 75. It also has to end in a 2 digit number under 40. How can I use substr to extract the first two digits and make sure they are under 75 and the last two digits and make sure they are under 40. I don't need anything complicated as it's for a single in house user on a private form. I can't just use < 7641 as 1849 is not okay (for instance).

Comment: this sounds like it might be better implemented as a Regular Expression instead.

Answer (score 2):

Notwithstanding the usual caveats about never validating a form only in JavaScript (rather than using a server-side language), REGEX is a good fit for this:

```
let
err,
val = form.redoarr.value
;
if (!val)
    err = 'No value entered';
else if (!/^([0-6][0-9]|7[0-4])([0-3][0-9])$/.test(val))
    err = 'Value must be four digits, with the first two under 75 and the last two under 40';

if (err) {
    form.redoarr.focus();
    alert(err);
    return false;
}
```

REGEX is cleaner as you don't need to create any variables. However here's how you'd do it via substring:

```
let
nums_1 = val.substr(0, 2),
nums_2 = val.substr(2)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution helps

```
var value = form.redoarr.value;
var re = /^\d{4}$/;
var error = '';
var first_two_digits = '';
var last_two_digits = '';

if ( !re.test(value) ) {
    error = 'Value must be four numbers';
}

first_two_digits = value.substr(0, 2);
last_two_digits = value.substr(2);

if (Number(first_two_digits) >= 75 || Number(last_two_digits) >= 40) {
    error = 'Invalid number provided';
}

if (error) {
    alert(error);
    return false;
}
```